# How to show Kendo-chart-title in new line

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to display title based on the value received from the backend. When text value is small it fits properly in the chart area. But when large text value is coming from backend, it gets hidden.

Is there any way we can push it to a new line when large text value is returned from the server.

I am aware of \n which moves the text to a new line. But my data is dynamic so I am not sure when to add \n. Any help will be highly appreciated.

One way I am thinking is to count the length of string and add '\n' not sure if this will be a right approach.

Here is my code:

/*app.component.ts**/

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div id="chart-wrapper">
    <kendo-chart [seriesColors]="['orange', '#ffe']">
    <kendo-chart-title text={{title}}></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-legend position="top"></kendo-chart-legend>
      <kendo-chart-area background="#eee" [margin]="0"> </kendo-chart-area>
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="pie"
          [data]="pieData"
          field="value"
          categoryField="category">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
    <div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public pieData: any = [
    { category: 'Eaten', value: 0.42 },
    { category: 'Not eaten', value: 0.58 }
  ]

  public title = "this is test title to check whether it breaks in new line or not";
}
```

Stackblitz for the issue:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqdtsd?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: The Stackblitz link redirects me to the homepage.

Comment: @TudorCiotlos Updated stackblitz

Comment: Can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: Since the component is rendered with Canvas, you'd have a lot of work to break that line. What you could do is implement a function to add `\n` on the string as you want. It's not elegant nor a best practice but would do the work.

Comment: @YgorAzevedo Chart is rendered as SVG. Will it make any difference ??

Comment: Not that I know but I'm not a Canvas or SVG expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to fix this is to format your title on your component. Just add **`"\n"`** to the title it will break down into lines

```
public title = "this is test \n title to check whether it breaks in new line or not";
```

here is a logic

```
this.title = this.title.replace(/(.{30})/g,"\n")
```

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqdtsd-sbdbkt?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: it removes some text of title as well

Comment: That's just a logic , you need to modify as you need

Comment: @Amit did the answer help?

Comment: This was not the approach I was looking for but this will solve my problem.
Thanks